# Using PostgreSQL 9.X with C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4, connector

When I try to connect to postgresql 9.2 with c++ it's not working in Windows but I can do that with postgresql 8.4. I heard that I can connect using ODBC with MFC.

Is there any other simple way to use postgresql with C++?

EDIT:

One of Error message is: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQclear referenced in function "void __cdecl queryExecuterWithGlobalConn(char const *)"

When I search for that I saw it's a common issue in PostgreSQL 9.X but I didn't find a solution.
By the way it's working with cygwin but not with MinGW and cl.

Comment: Something happened somewhere?

Comment: Did you compile with `-lpq` or include `libpq.a`?

Comment: FYI there is no meaningful "PostgreSQL 9.x"; 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2 are distinct major releases. Yes, this is counter-intuitive. As for "C++": *Do you really mean **Microsoft Visual C++ 11.0 (2012
)**?* "C++" is a language, not a compiler, toolchain, or toolchain release version. You refer to both MinGW and `cl` ... which are you using?

Comment: Yes I added required libraries.

Comment: @CraigRinger I mentioned that it worked with cygwin but mingw and cl.

Comment: @Yavuz "cl" part of Microsoft Visual Studio. MinGW is part of the Minimal GNU for Windows compiler toolchain. They're separate things. There's also a huge difference between `cl.exe` 6.0 and `cl.exe` 11.0 for example. **Details** are vital. Are you building with `make`? with `nmake`? with `msbuild`? with a project file? What MSVC version? What MinGW version and what are you using MinGW for?

Answer (score 0):

Use Npgsql. It is a native library (. Net Data Provider for Postgresql) example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

public class NpgsqlUserManual
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
         NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=joe;Password=secret;Database=joedata;");
         conn.Open();
         conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for c++, not .Net.